# React Render additional components onClick. Optimal pattern in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

New to React, enjoying it so far.

I have a situation where the parent renders both:

1. A TagBuilderContainer (a data layer containing initially 1 TagBuilderComponent)
2. An "Add Tag" button with an onClick event (with the aim to be used to add a new TagBuilderComponent inside TagBuilderContainer on each and every click)

Wondering if there is a prefered/optimal pattern for adding any number of a certain component during a users session.

Some example code

```
var TagBuilderParent = React.createClass({

  _newTagSelected() {
   //code to be added. something to handle event and drive new component creation
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="well">
        <TagBuilderContainer
          templateContext={this.props.templateContext} />
        <button onClick={this._newTagSelected} className="btn btn-sm"><i className="fa fa-tag"></i> Add Tag</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var TagBuilderContainer = React.createClass({

  componentWillMount() {
    let _this = this;
    collectedInstanceTags = new ReactiveVar([]);
    Meteor.call('getAllMatchingTagsFromCollection', this.props.templateContext.data.selectedAccount, function(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('error', err);
      } else {
        console.log('setting reactive variable');
        collectedInstanceTags.set(res);
      }
    });

    this.setState({collectedInstanceTags: collectedInstanceTags});
  },

  componentDidMount() {},

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='tagGroup' ref='tagGroup'>
        <TagBuilder
          collectedInstanceTags={this.state.collectedInstanceTags.get()} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var TagBuilder = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      userSelectedKey: '',
      userSelectedValue: ''
    };
  },

  componentDidMount() {},

  _populateTagKeyOptions(tag, index) {
    return (
      <option value={tag.Key} key={index}>{tag.Key}</option>
    );
  },

  _setUserSelectedTag(event) {
    this.setState({userSelectedKey: event.target.value});
  },

  _populateTagValueOptions(tag, index) {
    let matchingTagValue;
    if (this.state.userSelectedKey === tag.Key) {
      matchingTagValue = <option value={tag.Value} key={index}><div>{tag.Value}</div></option>;
    }

    return (
      matchingTagValue
    );
  },

  render() {
    let tagValues;
    if (!_.isEmpty(this.state.userSelectedKey)) {
      tagValues =   this.props.collectedInstanceTags.map(this._populateTagValueOptions);
    }

    return (
      <div className="tag-build-component input-group pull-right">
        <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-tag"> </i></span>
      <select onChange={this._setUserSelectedTag} name="tag-key-selection" className="form-control input-sm">
        {this.props.collectedInstanceTags.map(this._populateTagKeyOptions)}
      </select>
      <select onChange={this._userSelectedValue} name="tag-value-selection" className="form-control input-sm">
        {tagValues}
      </select>
    </div>
   );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to approach, But usually data flows in react are recommended to go from higher level components to lower level. Lower level components are pure dumb components that take props and render. Higher level component usually owns data and passes them as props to lower level components. In this case `TagBuilderParent` can have a `collectedInstanceTags` state. It can do the fetching and pass `collectedInstanceTags`  as props to `TagBuilderContainer`. As new tag is added you can do the refetching and set the collectedInstanceTags state. This will lead to render being called.